# I was trying to make a music discord bot and he's not responding

Tags: python, discord

The error that im facing is:

`2023-02-28 19:02:09 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found`

Here's the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext  import commands
import youtube_dl

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self,ctx):
      if ctx.author.voice is None:
          await ctx.send("Dsh alroom okay???")
      voice_chennel = ctx.author.voice.channel
      if ctx.voice_client is None:
          await voice_chennel.connect()
      else:
          await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_chennel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(slef,ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self,ctx,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
```

Hoping if the discord don't took of the play commande from bots.

I searched around and didn't find any solving for the idea.

Comment: Where are you defining your bot? These are just the commands.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.